# Overloading + operator to concatenate 2 doubly lists

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to read 2 lists and concatenate them overloading + operator. I am pretty new in classes so please be patient with me, all I want is to learn. I overloaded the stream operators so I can read and write the objects normal and reversed . My + operator does concatenate the lists but the problems seems to be in main ( list1=list1+list2; or writing list3 -after concatenating list1 and list2 ). I looked almost everywhere on the internet for an answer and I ended posting this. If you have any links or tutorials that can make me grow faster and easier I am opened to new ideas. Thank alot for reading this and tryng to help ^^

Node Class:

```
class nod
{
public:
    int data;
    nod *next;
    nod *prev;
    friend class Lista;
    nod();
};
```

List Class

```
class Lista
{
private:
    nod *head;
    nod *tail;
    int size;
public:
    Lista();
    ~Lista();
    friend istream &operator >>(istream &input, Lista &a)
    {
        int i;
        cout << "Size of the list: ";
        input >> a.size;
        nod *q = new nod;
        q->prev = NULL;
        cout << "\nFrist node: ";
        input >> q->data;
        a.head = q;
        a.tail = a.head;
        for (i = 1; i < a.size; i++)
        {
            nod *q = new nod;
            cout << "\nNode number " << i + 1 << " is: ";
            input >> q->data;
            a.tail->next = q;
            q->prev = a.tail;
            a.tail = q;
            a.tail->next = NULL;
        }
        return input;
    }

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &output, Lista &a)
    {
        output << "\n\nNormal writing: ";
        nod *q = new nod;
        q = a.head;
        while (q != NULL)
        {
            output << q->data << " ";
            q = q->next;
        }
        q = a.tail;
        output << "\n\nReverse writing: ";

        while (q != NULL)
        {
            output << q->data << " ";
            q = q->prev;
        }
        return output;
    }
    Lista &operator+(Lista &rec)
    {
        Lista temp;
        temp.head = head;
        temp.tail = tail;
        temp.tail->next = rec.head;
        rec.head->prev = temp.tail;
        temp.tail = rec.tail;
        temp.size = size;
        temp.size = temp.size + rec.size;
        return temp;
    }
};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    Lista a,b,c;
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    c=a+b;
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not following [the rule of 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  You cannot possibly start doing anything with `operator +` until you write a user-defined copy constructor.  Also, this type of coding is not for beginners, but for experienced C++ coders.  I have yet to see a beginner get this correct without having an experienced coder basically writing the whole thing for them.

Comment: So if I wan to use " c=a+b " I also have to overload the = operator?

Comment: You need to follow the rule of 3.  That means you must implement copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor, *and they must work correctly*.  As to what you've already coded, there are a lot of things that should be done differently -- what if I want to add an item to the list, and I don't want to use a stream?  As my first comment suggested, this will turn into me or some other SO member's either directing you to code already written, or we write the whole thing ourselves to show you how to properly do this.  A beginner *never* gets this correct, believe me.

Comment: I also did adding and deleting items methods. I just didn't see it important so I didn't put it here. I am not a begginer in C++. I am a begginer in "Classes Chapter" and I did research to get to this code. Didn't get it perfectly but this is all I could do alone. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Yes, by this you are damn right. I just tried to get it as easy as I could for me. But I will listen your advice and learn some class design asap. Thanks alot again for your patience!

Comment: You're still a beginner.  When I mean beginner, I mean one that does not have the experience of knowing how to handle memory management, pointers, does not know proper class design and cannot debug without help.   You **can't** do this alone, again, believe me.  Get an example of a properly coded linked list class that has the proper operations coded correctly and learn from that example.  Don't do this yourself -- you won't get it right (and I've been seeing attempts at this for many years now -- still waiting for that beginner to ace this by themselves).

Comment: I think what's best is to view how a linked list class is properly coded first.  Then ask questions on "why did they do this?" or "why did they do that?"  That is far more productive than trying to do this blindly and coming up short.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator+` is not even close to being a correct implementation. For starters, you are returning a reference to a local variable that goes out of scope upon exit, destroying the list and leaving the caller with a dangling reference to invalid memory.  But worse, you are making that local variable point at the nodes of your input lists, and you are manipulating the various pointers within those lists, corrupting both lists.

`operator+` needs to return a *copy* of the data from the two input lists.  That means allocating a whole new set of nodes for the output list.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class nod
{
public:
    int data;
    nod *next;
    nod *prev;

    nod(int value = 0) :
        data(value), next(NULL), prev(NULL)
    {
    }
};
```

```
class Lista
{
private:
    nod *head;
    nod *tail;
    int size;

public:
    Lista() :
        head(NULL), tail(NULL), size(0)
    {
    }

    Lista(const Lista &src) :
        head(NULL), tail(NULL), size(0)
    {
        *this = src;
    }

    ~Lista()
    {
        Clear();
    }

    void Add(int value)
    {
        node *n = new nod(value);
        n->prev = tail;
        if (!head) head = n;
        if (tail) tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
        ++size;
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        nod *n = head;
        head = tail = NULL;
        size = 0;
        while (n)
        {
            nod *next = n->next;
            delete n;
            n = next;
        }
    }

    Lista& operator=(const Lista &rhs)
    {
        Clear();
        nod *n = rhs.head;
        while (n)
        {
            Add(n->data);
            n = n->next;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Lista operator+(const Lista &rhs)
    {
        Lista temp;

        nod *n = head;
        while (n)
        {
            temp.Add(n->data);
            n = n->next;
        }

        n = rhs.head;
        while (n)
        {
            temp.Add(n->data);
            n = n->next;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &input, Lista &a);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &output, const Lista &a);
};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &input, Lista &a)
{
    // NOTE: this kind of code really does not
    // belong in an 'operator>>' implementation!

    int i, size, data;
    std::cout << "Size of the list: ";
    input >> size;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\nNode number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        input >> data;
        a.Add(data);
    }
    return input;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &output, const Lista &a)
{
    output << "\n\nNormal writing: ";
    nod *n = a.head;
    while (n)
    {
        output << n->data << " ";
        n = n->next;
    }

    n = a.tail;
    output << "\n\nReverse writing: ";
    while (n)
    {
        output << n->data << " ";
        n = n->prev;
    }

    return output;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    Lista a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;
    c = a + b;
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, with that said, you should seriously get rid of the manual linked-list implementation and use the STL [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) class instead, which manages a linked-list of nodes and knows how to make copies of itself:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class Lista
{
private:
    std::list<int> data;

public:
    void Add(int value)
    {
        data.push_back(value);
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        data.clear();
    }

    Lista operator+(const Lista &rhs)
    {
        Lista temp;
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
        std::copy(rhs.data.begin(), rhs.data.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
        return temp;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &input, Lista &a);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &output, const Lista &a);
};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &input, Lista &a);
{
    // NOTE: this kind of code really does not
    // belong in an 'operator>>' implementation!

    int i, size, data;
    std::cout << "Size of the list: ";
    input >> size;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\nNode number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        input >> data;
        a.Add(data);
    }
    return input;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &output, const Lista &a)
{
    output << "\n\nNormal writing: ";
    for (std::list<int>::const_iterator iter = a.data.begin(), end = a.data.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        output << *iter << " ";
    }

    output << "\n\nReverse writing: ";
    for (std::list<int>::const_reverse_iterator iter = a.data.rbegin(), end = a.data.rend(); iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        output << *iter << " ";
    }

    return output;
}
```